# Antlr Fails to install in VS2010 via Nuget with error: External packages cannot depend on packages that target projects

Tags: antlr4

Antler lists StackOverflow as its support site. So here's my support question. When I attempt to install the ANTLR 4 parser generator package, `Antlr4` specifically, for Visual Studio 2010+ projects (version 4.5.3.1-beta001) via NuGet 2.8.60318.667, I get the following error:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Antlr4.CodeGenerator (≥ 4.5.3.1-beta001)'.
External packages cannot depend on packages that target projects.
```

How do I work around this and get the ANTLR code generator installed?

Comment: Please file this as an issue [on the project](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/issues).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's actually a bug report for an open source project

Comment: I'm not sure if it's strictly a bug. I took another look at it this morning--I was attempting to install the wrong package--but the package naming is confusing. It almost looks like there's an extra package in NuGet for ANTLR.

Comment: I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/1267). I'm still not positive this isn't just something I don't understand about NuGet. But if this is a valid bug, I have no problem with this question being closed.

Answer (score 1):

As of at least version 4.5.3.1-beta001, generating C# with ANTLR 4 requires two NuGet packages: `Antlr4.Runtime` and `Antlr4.CodeGenerator`. Another package, `Antlr4` depends on these two. Presently, attempting to install `Antlr4` throws the error in the question above. However, if you install `Antlr4.Runtime` and then `Antlr4.CodeGenerator`, the install will work fine.